# Sum of parts in a list

Tags: python, arrays

I wrote this code:

```
arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
arr1 = []
count = 0
arr.append(0) # i forgot to wrote this line. 
for i in range(0, len(arr)):
    count = sum(arr) 
    arr.remove(arr[0])
    arr1.append(count)
print(arr1)
```

The output is:
[20, 20, 19, 16, 10, 0]

But I have a little problem. Time of execution it is a little bit to long for large lists. 
Can u tell me  if exist another mode to write it?

Thx!

Comment: just sayin', when I run your code I get `[21, 20, 18, 15, 11, 6]`

Comment: Why count everything again? If you remove a value from the list, just subtract it from the previous count.

Comment: Also, you could build the counts the other way round, starting from the end and adding, and reverse the list of counts at the end if you really need to.

Comment: I forgot to mention, list must contain 0 and i used arr.append(0)

Comment: what is the expected result?  Do elements order counts?

Comment: It s not necessary to order counts.The inital array is [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] and the expected output is [21, 20, 18, 15, 11, 6, 0], idk how to add 0 in arr.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `python`, removing the first element of a `list` requires all the subsequent elements to be moved and therefore takes **O(n)**. Since you're doing that `n` times (with `n` being the length of your array), the overall [time complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity) of your solution is **O(n<sup>2</sup>)**

Any solution that only runs in **O(n)** time complexity should be fine for you. Here is one that doesn't require any external imports and is similar in style to your original solution:

```py
arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
total = sum(arr)
sums = [total]
for to_remove in arr[:-1]:
    total -= to_remove
    sums.append(total)

print(sums)
[21, 20, 18, 15, 11, 6]
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest `itertools.accumulate`

```
from itertools import accumulate
from operator import add

result = list(accumulate(reversed(arr), add))[::-1]
```

---

With a few test it's a lot more performant, for 20k digits

```
accumulate 0:00:00.004001
question   0:00:05.340281
```

Comment: I forgot to mention, list must contain 0  and i used arr.append(0), probably this is the problem..

Comment: @Rares Where should the 0 be ? I don't see this line in your code, could edit your post to add it ?

Comment: For list of a few tens of values, `result = list(accumulate(reversed(arr), add))[::-1]` is faster (and about 20% faster for large lists), as it doesn't have to build the reversed list. For small lists, the difference is negligible.

Answer (score 0):

It is not perfect but a little faster:

```
import timeit

def function():
  arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
  arr1 = []
  count = 0

  for i in range(0, len(arr)):
      count = sum(arr) 
      arr.remove(arr[0])
      arr1.append(count)
  return arr1

print(timeit.timeit(function))
```

`Time: 1.9620031519999657`

```
import timeit
def function():
  arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
  arr1 = [sum(arr)]

  i = 0
  while i < len(arr)-1:
    arr1.append(arr1[i] - arr[i])
    i = i +1
  arr1.append(arr1[-1]-arr[-1])
  return arr1

print(timeit.timeit(function))
```

`Time: 1.408351424999978`

Answer (score 0):

If you are every time conscious, always try to use libraries like **`numpy`**.

In numpy this will be every easy, and efficient.

```py
import numpy
a = numpy.arange(7) # since you also want to include 6 in array, 0, 1, 2, ..., 5, 6
np.cumsum(a[::-1])[::-1]
```

You would need to install **`numpy`** separately. If you don't know you can install **`numpy`** by:

```
pip install numpy
```